# Android on back press user should remain in the same page

Tags: android

In my activity page i have two option- normal screen and edit mode screen.Both screen are in the same activity.

When the user enters the activity the normal page is shown.when he clicks on a button the edit mode is shown.if normal screen is there then on back press user should go back to the previous activity.But if edit mode is on and the user clicks on back button then instead of going back to the previous activity,user should be shown the normal screen.

my onbackpressed method is

```
if(inputSearch.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE){     
        Intent intentList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),listsActivity.class);
        intentList.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intentList);          
        }
        else{                   
            imgEditList.setSelected(false);
            editMode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            inputSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }       
        super.onBackPressed();
```

What is the use of finish().Does it close the present activity or...

Comment: You should not call `super.onBackPressed();` if you don't want to close the current activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
if(inputSearch.getVisibility()== View.VISIBLE){     
    Intent intentList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),listsActivity.class);
    intentList.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intentList);          
    }
    else{                   
        imgEditList.setSelected(false);
        editMode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        inputSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return;
    }       
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: this works. Can you please explain this.And what is the use of finish()

Comment: @Ciff it's simple: when you're in Edit Mode, and then push back Activity doesn't finish, because not satisfied "super.onBackPressed();"

Comment: @Ciff bout second question try to understand [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/app/Activity.html) - it's very important for all android developers.